# Run the Delay task in Azure pipeline for atleast x minutes simultaneously with previous jobs

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We have a Azure release pipeline.
The structure of the pipeline is

- Agent Job 1

  - Task 1
  - Task 2
- Agentless Job

  - Delay (10 minutes)
- Agent Job 2

  - Task 3

Delay is added since we want task 3 to run 10 minutes after the release. But the issue here is that since the jobs run sequentially, task 3 waits not only for the 10 minutes of delay but also whatever time tasks 1 and 2 take (usually 7 mins each). This adds some unnecessary wait time.

What I'm aiming for is either :

1. Make Agent job 1 and Agentless Job both run simultaneously so that Job 2 starts immediately after whichever previous job takes more time.
2. Somehow modify the delay time so that it's not a fixed 10 minutes but something like `max(0, 10 - agent job 1 time in minutes)`. This might be possible using output variables but haven't been able to figure this out.

How can I achieve this using one of the above ways or some other design if possible ?

Answer (score 0):

> Delay is added since we want task 3 to run 10 minutes after the
> release. But the issue here is that since the jobs run sequentially

You could set Agent Job 1 and Agentless Job to run parallel, Agent Job 2 depends on Agentless job to achieve your aim 1.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

If the Agent Job 1 takes 14 mins, and you want the Agent Job 2 starts after 10 minutes delay, make sure you have one more [parallel job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops&tabs=ms-hosted) available for Agent Job 2.

Comment: I am talking about the release pipelines though, not the build pipelines. I don't see a way of running two jobs in parallel here nor the "Dependencies' option like in your screenshot.